# Sorting a dictionary (on key) using a custom comparer for SortDescription

Tags: c#, xaml, sorting, compare, collectionviewsource

I have a property: `ObservableDictonary<string, CustomClass> ModuleConnections` and have created a collection view source like so:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ModuleConnectionSorter" Source="{Binding ModuleConnections}">
    <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Key" Direction="Ascending"/>
     </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

which uses:

```
xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
```

I have also created my own comparer:

```
public class AddressComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string firstAddress, string secondAddress)
    {
        uint firstTddressInteger = AddressToUint(firstAddress);
        uint secondAddressInteger = AddressToUint(secondAddress);
        if (firstAddressInteger < secondAddressInteger)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (firstAddressInteger > secondAddressInteger)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static uint AddressToUint(string Address)
    {
        var addressIP = IPAddress.Parse(Address).GetAddressBytes();
        Array.Reverse(addressIP);
        return BitConverter.ToUInt32(addressIP, 0);
    }
}
```

The internet has given me this option:

```
private void MainWindowLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionViewSource source = (CollectionViewSource)(this.Resources["ModuleConnectionSorter"]);
    ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)source.View;
    view.CustomSort = (IComparer)new TCAddressComparer();
}
```

However I cannot do this because I get a 'System.InvalidCastException' with the following error:

```
Cannot convert object of type MS.Internal.Data.EnumerableCollectionView to System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.
```

This has probably to do with the fact that I do not bind a list but a [ObservableDictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) (which is practically the same as a Dictionary)

So since I cannot do it the normal way (which I don't like anyway) I thought i would create my own SortDescription a CustomSortDescription if you will. When i thought of doing that I wonderd why no one else did it that way, well it quite quickly became clear to me that that wasn't going to be a solution either.

I thought (naive me) that i would simply inherit sortdescription and create my own derived version:

```
public class CustomSortDescription : SortDescription
```

Can anyone help me sort things out? I simply want to sort an ObservableDictionary on the key (string).

**Update:** 
I have made a work around, well not much of a work around more a work another way. But what I am doing now is everytime i add something to the dictionary I sort the dictionary like so:

```
var sortedIOrderedEnumerable = this.ModuleConnections.OrderBy(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key, new TCAddressComparer());
mModuleConnections = new ObservableDictionary<string, ModuleConnection>(sortedIOrderedEnumerable.ToDictionary(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value));
RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ModuleConnections);
```

This is not how it should be done and I am still looking for a way to do the sorting for the view (and not the data source) in XAML code.

Comment: can you try view.ToList().

    **view.ToList().CustomSort = (IComparer)new TCAddressComparer();**

Comment: @AnılOkay Unfortunatly CollectionViewSource does not have a ToList method.

Comment: I wonder Vincent if you ever found a way to get this to work as I have ran into a similar issue.

Comment: No i sticked with the 'workaround' i posted in the update and that was it. never had the time to revisit this unfortunatly